# How can this recursive code can be understood?

Tags: java, recursion, int, return

```
int j(int i) {
    if (i==0) return 2;
    return i*j(i-1);
}
```

calling `j(4)` gives 48.

I feel like I do understand the code, but don't know how 48 was achieved.

This is how I interpret it,

```
int j(4){
```

4 is not equal to 0 so it won't return 2

```
4*j(i-1) = 4*j(3)
```

then i go back to the top and repeat

```
3*j(2)
2*j(1)
1*j(0)
```

now i return 2.

This is where  am lost, i'm not quite sure what to do after this step and how the answer to j(4) is 48.

Comment: So what were you expecting 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 x 2 to be?

Comment: Paper + pencil + effort = understanding

Comment: Stepping + through + with + a + debugger = enlightenment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The evaluation can be understood like this

```
j(4)
4 * j(3)
4 * (3 * j(2))
4 * (3 * (2 * j(1)))
4 * (3 * (2 * (1 * j(0))))   // When input to j is 0, returns 2
4 * (3 * (2 * (1 * 2)))
4 * (3 * (2 * 2))
4 * (3 * 4)
4 * 12
48
```

Till recursion reaches `j(0)`, it goes deeper and deeper. But when it reaches it, it begins to unwind the recursion. And the most important thing is,

```
if (i==0) return 2;
```

is called the base condition of your recursion.

Comment: @newCoder You are welcome :) We all have struggled understanding this. But, once you understand it, you will love them :-)

Answer (score 4):

`j(0)` clearly returns 2, right?

So `j(1)` returns `1*j(0)`, and `j(0)` is 2. So `j(1)` returns `2*1`, or 2.

`j(2)` returns `2*j(1)` or `2*2` or 4.

`j(3)` returns `3*j(2)` or `3*4` or 12.

`j(4)` returns `4*j(3)` or `4*12` or 48.

Answer (score 0):

so this is calling

return 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 0 (no not 0 use 2)

result 48

Answer (score 0):

You can trace through it:

```
j(4) = 4 * j(3) = 4 * (3 * j(2)) = 4 * 3 * 2 * j(1) 
     = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * j(0) = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 2 = 48
```